# Take photo & upload to server in Android

Tags: java, android, http, http-post

I'm trying to take a photo on android and sending it to server using POST method. I have searched alot on stackoverflow and the code I have right now is based on other answers but I still can't send to the server.The parameter name of the image should be "file" in my POST request. I debugged and response is empty and contentlegth is -1. here is my code:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload_data, container, false);
    TextView barcodeText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);
    Button picButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.take_picture);
    picButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            String file = "img.jpg";
            File newfile =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), file);
            file= newfile.getAbsolutePath();
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
        }
    });
    barcodeText.setText(barcode);
    return v;
}
```

and here is my onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/img.jpg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
        byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file",image_str));
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.fakeURL);
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    final String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Response "+the_string_response , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }catch(final Exception e){
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                               Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
```

I also have the BASE64.java in my classes. Can anyone tell me what is wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the bitmap to an imageview to make sure the image bitmap is there, After that use "BitmapFactory.Options" from here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html to avoid out of memory error.

**EDIT** : Try this compression also.

```
String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: thanks the image loads in the imageview, I ended up not using Base64 and bitmap and directly sending the file using multipartEntity